# How do I set up an application proxy behind gitlabs login?

Tags: gitlab

I'm interested in using gitlab as an authentication layer for other web apps that are on the same machine. Is there an easy way to make gitlab proxy requests for a given url path to other servers on the local network while requiring that the request came from an user logged into gitlab?